# Read certain key from certain section of ini file (sed/awk ?)

Tags: file, sed, awk, ini

I need to retrieve the value of a key from an ini file with typical structure:

```
[abcd]
key1=a
key2=b
[efgh]
key1=c
key2=d
[hijk]
key1=e
key2=f
```

with key names repeated in different sections, and no consistant naming/order of sections.  How could I find key1 from efgh?  If I grep then I'll find all key1's (and I don't know the order of the sections).

I suspect sed or awk can do this but I can't find it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could be a start:

```
awk -F'=' -v section="[efgh]" -v k="key1"  '
$0==section{ f=1; next }  # Enable a flag when the line is like your section
/\[/{ f=0; next }         # For any lines with [ disable the flag
f && $1==k{ print $0 }    # If flag is set and first field is the key print key=value
' ini.file
```

You pass two variables, `section` and `k`. `section` needs to contain the section you want to look under. `k` should contain the `key` you are trying to obtain value for.

Find value of `key1` under section `[efgh]`:

```
$ awk -F'=' -v section="[efgh]" -v k="key1"  '
$0==section{ f=1; next }  
/\[/{ f=0; next }         
f && $1==k{ print $0 }      
' ini.file
key1=c
```

Find value of `key2` under section `[hijk]`:

```
$ awk -F'=' -v section="[hijk]" -v k="key2"  '
$0==section{ f=1; next }  
/\[/{ f=0; next }         
f && $1==k{ print $0 }      
' ini.file
key2=f
```

Comment: @Michelle Can you elaborate what doesn't work? Error? Not finding anything? Post relevant dataset in your question. This one just prints the value. Do you want the entire `key=value` pair?

Answer (score 5):

Using sed

```
sed -r ':a;$!{N;ba};s/.*\[efgh\][^[]*(key1=[^\n]*).*/\1/' file

key1=c
```

another way

```
sed -nr '/\[efgh\]/,/\[/{/key1/p}' file
```

Comment: Slurping the entire file like that might not be a great idea.

Comment: Good suggestion, how about second one? I made it from @Guru's idea.

Comment: People who complain that Perl is unreadable should try sed ... :-). However, that maze of backslashes in the 2nd example worked perfectly for what I wanted!

Answer (score 4):

One way:

```
sed -n '/\[efgh\]/,/\[.*\]/p' file | awk -F= '/key2/{print $2}'
```

Using sed, extract the range of lines from [efgh] to the next [....] pattern. Using awk, search for key2 in this range of lines and get the value.

Comment: You can actually avoid `awk` by doing `sed -nr '/\[efgh\]/,/\[.*\]/{/key1/s/(.*)=(.*)/\2/p}' file`

Answer (score 3):

These `sed` one-liners worked for me, shamelessly copied from [github:thomedes/ini.sed](https://gist.github.com/thomedes/6201620)

```
#  List all [sections] of a .INI file
sed -n 's/^[ \t]*\[\(.*\)\].*/\1/p'

#  Read KEY from [SECTION]
sed -n '/^[ \t]*\[SECTION\]/,/\[/s/^[ \t]*KEY[ \t]*=[ \t]*//p'

#  Read all values from SECTION in a clean KEY=VALUE form
sed -n '/^[ \t]*\[SECTION\]/,/\[/s/^[ \t]*\([^#; \t][^ \t=]*\).*=[ \t]*\(.*\)/\1=\2/p'

# examples:
sed -n 's/^[ \t]*\[\(.*\)\].*/\1/p' /etc/samba/smb.conf
sed -n '/^[ \t]*\[global\]/,/\[/s/^[ \t]*workgroup[ \t]*=[ \t]*//p' /etc/samba/smb.conf
sed -n '/^[ \t]*\[global\]/,/\[/s/^[ \t]*\([^#; \t][^ \t=]*\).*=[ \t]*\(.*\)/\1=\2/p' /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -rn '/^\[/{h;d};G;s/^key1=(.*)\n\[efgh\]$/\1/p' file
```

Copy the section header and compare it against the section body.