# Getting values from properties file using shell from a specific section

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I'm trying to Get values from a properties file (ansible hosts file) using shell script from a specific section of the hosts file.

So I have this hosts file:

```
[windows]
myd-vm14945.company.net
myd-vm01431.company.net

[windows-web]
vmpweb314.company.net

[linux]
myd-vm11409.company.net
myd-vm14296.company.net
myd-vm20125.company.net
mydvm0091.company.net
```

And this script I want to run, when  every server under **Linux** section should replace the parameter **${REMOTE_SERVER}** in the shell script:

```
#add remote server to ansible host known_host file
ssh-keyscan ${REMOTE_SERVER}>> /root/.ssh/known_hosts
#remmber password
sshpass -p ROOT_PASSWORD ssh root@${REMOTE_SERVER}
```

So that the final result will be like that:

```
#add remote server to ansible host known_host file
ssh-keyscan myd-vm11409.company.net >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts
ssh-keyscan myd-vm14296.company.net>> /root/.ssh/known_hosts
#remmber password
sshpass -p ROOT_PASSWORD ssh root@myd-vm11409.company.net
sshpass -p ROOT_PASSWORD ssh root@myd-vm14296.company.net
```

And so on...for all the values under Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to do it from bash, see the following `awk` magic, partially taken from [Read certain key from certain section of ini file (sed/awk ?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22550265/read-certain-key-from-certain-section-of-ini-file-sed-awk)

So you can create the following script, adjust for your inventory file and section and run it!

**addkeys.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
INVENTORY="inventory.ini"
SECTION="[linux]"

I_HOSTS="$(awk -v section="$SECTION" ' # Enable a flag when the line is like your section
$0==section{ f=1; next }               # For any lines with [ disable the flag
/\[/{ f=0; next }                      # If flag is set - print the line
f && $0' "$INVENTORY")"

for I_HOST in $I_HOSTS
do
    #add remote server to ansible host known_host file
    echo "ssh-keyscan "$I_HOST" >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts"
    #remmber password
    echo "sshpass -p ROOT_PASSWORD ssh "root@$I_HOST""
done
```

Results with echoed sshpass and keyscan commads:

```
ssh-keyscan myd-vm11409.company.net >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts
sshpass -p ROOT_PASSWORD ssh root@myd-vm11409.company.net
ssh-keyscan myd-vm14296.company.net >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts
sshpass -p ROOT_PASSWORD ssh root@myd-vm14296.company.net
ssh-keyscan myd-vm20125.company.net >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts
sshpass -p ROOT_PASSWORD ssh root@myd-vm20125.company.net
ssh-keyscan mydvm0091.company.net >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts
sshpass -p ROOT_PASSWORD ssh root@mydvm0091.company.net
```